# How to make three gridviews in the same page using tabs in Yii framework

Tags: php, gridview, yii, tabs

I'm new to Yii framework. Currently I have three models test1,test2,test3. I created admin pages for all the three models. So I can view gridview for each model individually.
Now , I want to use single page for all the three gridview. i.e I want to create three tabs in that page. Each tab should open a gridview of that corresponding model name.
How can I do this.

Comment: Add tabs and place one grid for each tab? What is your exact problem, please clarify.

Comment: did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'v passed $model and $form which is my active form to each tab by rendering it partially,
put your grids in 'view/_form_firstPart' and 'view/_form_second'

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
           'id' => 'tabs',
           'type' => 'tabs', // '', 'tabs', 'pills' (or 'list')
           'tabs' => array(
               array(
                   'label' => 'someLabel',
                   'content' => $this->renderPartial('_form_firstPart', array(
                                   'model' => $model,
                                   'form' => $form,
                               )
                          ,true),
                   'active' => true,
                   ),
               array(
                    'label' => 'anotherLabel',
                    'content' => $this->renderPartial('_form_second', array(
                         'model' => $model,
                         'form' => $form,
                     ) ,true),
               ),
            )));
```

Comment: Which file is ideal to insert this tabs.Should I create a new one or use any of the existing view files

Comment: if the tab ks usable in both update and create, then you can put it in _form. It's really whatever suites you best!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using bootstrap,than you can use cjuitabs,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(
            'tabs'=>array(
               'first model' =>array('content'=>$tab_1),
               'second model' =>array('content'=>$tab_2),

            ),
            // additional javascript options for the tabs plugin
            'options'=>array(
                    'collapsible'=>true,
            ),
     ));
```